# Kotlin: What is kotlin.String! type

Tags: kotlin

What is the meaning of the `kotlin.String!` type and how could I make the following code compile?

```
fun withDefault<A>(computation: () -> A, default: A) =
    try { computation() } catch (e: Exception) { default }

fun getHostname1() = withDefault(InetAddress.getLocalHost().getCanonicalHostName, "localhost")
```

The compiler prints the following error message:

```
Kotlin: Type inference failed: fun <A> withDefault(computation: () -> A, default: A): A
cannot be applied to
(kotlin.String!,kotlin.String)
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When the type ends with `!` it means that this is a platform type and compiler does not enforce null-safety for it. You can read about platform types in official [blog](http://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/2014/10/m9-is-here/), section `Platform Types`.

I suggest such fix:

```
fun getHostname1() = withDefault({ InetAddress.getLocalHost().getCanonicalHostName() } , "localhost")
```

Answer (score 4):

### Types suffixed with an `!` are called platform types

When interoperating with java, sometimes the java code contains nullability information such as `@Nullable` and `@NotNull` which kotlin uses to infer the types, for example `@Nullable String name` makes `name` to be of type `String?` in kotlin.

If however there is no such information available on types coming from java, then those types are called platform types and are marked with a `!`. In your case return type of `getCanonicalHostName` doesn't contain any such information, hence its shown as `kotlin.String!`

From [Kotlin in Action](https://www.manning.com/books/kotlin-in-action)

> **PLATFORM TYPES**
>
> A platform type is essentially a type for which Kotlin doesn’t have
> nullability information; you can work with it as either a nullable or
> a nonnull type. This means, just as in Java, you have
> full responsibility for the operations you perform with that type. The
> compiler will allow all operations. It also won’t highlight as
> redundant any null-safe operations on such values, which it normally
> does when you perform a null-safe operation on a value of a non-null
> type. If you know the value can be null, you can compare it with null
> before use. If you know it’s not null, you can use it directly. Just
> as in Java, you’ll get a NullPointerException at the usage site if you
> get this wrong.

As for the error, it occurs because first argument to `withDefault` is of functional type, but you are passing a kotlin.String!, which is clearly not a function.