# Invoke Java Method From Kotlin with List Parameter

Tags: java, list, kotlin

I want to call a Java method from some kotlin code

```
val list: List<String> = emptyList()
repository.find(list) // this call goes to a java class
```

IntelliJ is informing me about a type mismatch:

> Type mismatch.
>    Required: (Mutuable)Set<String!>
>    Found: List<String>

My method signature in Java:

```
void find(@Nonnull Set<String> list);
```

I understand that this can't go well and [according to the doc](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#mapped-types), I could use a *MutableList* in Kotlin instead. But I have full control over the Java Code too and would like to change the Java code to work with Kotlin's *List*.

How does a Java method signature look like to accept Kotlin's List?

BTW: was is IntelliJ telling me with `Required: (Mutuable)Set<String!>`? What is the exclamation mark good for?

Comment: A `Set` is not a `List` and vice-versa. This is pretty clear.

Comment: It's "Mutable", not "Mutuable", and String! means that it's a platform type. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27460536/kotlin-what-is-kotlin-string-type

Comment: Thanks for your quick answers! It's a stupid question, I just mixed up Set and List types.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you really want to use a List, you need to change the signature of your Java method:

```
void find(@Nonnull List<String> list);
```

On the other hand, you can change the declaration of your variable in Kotlin:

```
val set: Set<String> = emptySet()
repository.find(set)
```

Or per Jakob Bowyer's comment and answer, you can let Kotlin infer the argument type:

```
val set = emptySet<String>()
repository.find(set)
```

Comment: It is more common to put the generic in the function call and let kotlin infer the type.

Comment: @JakobBowyer - good to know. I have not played around with Kotlin yet, so this was just going off pure JVM type-safety knowledge.

Comment: Would the drive-by downvoter care to explain their downvote and how I might be able to improve this answer?

Answer (score 1):

Why not 

`val list = emptySet<String>()
repository.find(list) // this call goes to a java class`

Answer (score 0):

If you have a `List` and want to pass it to (java) function taking a `Set`, you can convert the list with `toSet` extension function:

```
repository.find(list.toSet())
```